# Using an array outside the function of origin

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function, parameters

I´m storing some values in an array and print them on an HTML page with Javascript. So far so good.
Now I want to use the same data in the array for a data graphic. But I can´t get the array out of the function in which I created the array. I can´t event print it out as I did before from inside the function.
This doesn´t seem impossible, but I don´t get it.
I tried to define a getter function, but I wasn´t successful.
Maybe someone can help me.

By the way, I received the data from a node.js server via Socket.io.
On http://jsfiddle.net/dL3Lsx0L/ I reduced the code and strangely it works there, but not in my original code below.

```
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
    <script src='//localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script>

        var socket = io();
        var values_array = new Array();

        socket.on('server2browser', function(data)        // Receive data from server
        {
            fct_values_array(data);   
        });


        function fct_values_array(data)     
        {
             $.each(data, function(i, obj)                // Store received data in array
             {
                 values_array[i] = obj.numbers;      
             });         
             $('#arrayprint_values').text(values_array);  // Print array on HTML - It works.
        }


        $('#printagain').text(values_array);              // Print array again - Doesn´t work.
    </script>
```

Comment: The only time that `values_array` is modified is when `fct_values_array` is called. By the time we reach `$('#printagain')...` it hasn't been modified (probably) because `socket.on` is an asynchronous method? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you use `console.log()` to print the values you'll likely find that the code isn't running in the order that you expect. Printing to two separate html elements doesn't show you the timing.

Comment: Qantas´ link was very helpful. Yes, it might be a duplicate.
I replaced $('#arrayprint_values').text(values_array); with
setTimeout(function() 
{
$('#arrayprint_values').text(values_array);
}, Math.random() * 1000);

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:
Replace

`$('#arrayprint_values').text(values_array);`

by

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#arrayprint_values').text(values_array); 
}, Math.random() * 1000);
```

Comment: Never do that. It works only sometimes - by sheer luck, *randomly*.

Comment: Sometimes the data really needs some seconds. Better solution always welcome.